# VS2010 Add-in use own icon for custom add-in

Tags: visual-studio-2010, icons, add-in

I've programmed an add-in for VS2010, one of the code-lines from this add-in is:

```
Command command = commands.AddNamedCommand2(
_addInInstance, "MyAddIn", "MyAddIn", 
"bladiebla", true, 59, ref contextGUIDS, 
(int)vsCommandStatus.vsCommandStatusSupported
 + (int)vsCommandStatus.vsCommandStatusEnabled, 
(int)vsCommandStyle.vsCommandStylePictAndText, 
vsCommandControlType.vsCommandControlTypeButton);
```

The number 59 is the code of the icon to use.
Somehow when you use the number 59, a smiley appears as icon. Some testing did show that 47 shows an eraser, and 58 shows a x2-sign.

One question is where those icons come from?
Another question is how to add my own icon.
I tried:

```
var bitmap = new Bitmap(@"c:\myicon.ico");
```

and replace the number 59 with the bitmap object (this should be possible because the parameter for that function requests an object. But this did not work.

Answer (score 2):

Look at my bookmarks, these references should be of use to you:

> For information about how to find the ID numbers for standard icons, see [Listing Button Faces in the Command Bar for the Microsoft Office System](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135130) on the MSDN Web site.

How to: Change the Default Icon for an Add-In

ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165626(v=VS.100).aspx

How to: Display a Custom Icon on the Add-In Button

ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228771.aspx